# How to configure JSON for graphql query?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, shopify, graphql

I am trying to send queries to a Shopify site using the Storefront API provided. The API in question requires I use GraphQL, which is just JSON POSTed to a url endpoint. Given a query like this:

```
query {
  shop{
    products(first: 2) {
      edges {
        node {
          variants(first: 2) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I form the proper JSON such that the site responds appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST payload format is defined by the API developer. But typically it is like this:

`{"query": "query { ... }"}`

and oftentimes it includes a token, like this:

`{"query": "query { ... }", "token" : "..."}`

You are better off using a library, such as the [graphql-batch](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-batch) library offered by Shopify.

Comment: So all the other info (shop { ...) is all one string?

Comment: Yes just one long string starting with shop